# Вывод построчных структур из txt (CSV) в массив из структур (С)

Tags: c, структуры, csv

Программа выводит из текстового файла с структурами все в буфер, затем посимвольно записывает все в массив структур (каждой структуре своя строка).

Ориентируется на '\n'. Игнорирует пробелы и '\t'.

Предусмотрена проверка: в каждой структуре строго 5 элементов, причем в оценке char переводит в double (в последствие выводится только double с двумя знаками после запятой на печать). Также предусмотрена проверка ввода даты (строго dd.mm.yyyy).

В случае любой из описанных ошибок, кроме лишних пробелов или '\t', вся строка переносится в 'err.txt', а в текущую структуру записывается пустота. Следующая строка записывается в эту же структуру, если была ошибка из перечисленных.
На данном этапе программа должна вывести только исправные структуры, а испорченные в 'err.txt'.

Но дальше печати изначальных структур ничего не происходит. Почему не происходит вывод исправных, не понимаю. Возможно, неверно что-то инициализировал или еще что...

Наперед скажу, что понимаю, что программа, скорее всего, может быть реализована проще, короче и качественне благодаря библиотекам и прочему. Но сейчас нет возможности все разбить на функции и реализовать проверки специализированными методами. Честно говоря, пока не хватает знаний и понимания для реализации всего этого качественно.

Структура дана примерно таким файлом, содержащим ошибки.
(Имя;Фамилия;ДатаРождения;Номер;Оценка;\n)

Danils;  Grics;         04.12.1995; 161VDB231;  8.87;  23;

Andrejs;    Gregorjevs;     14.08.1996; 161RDB223;  7.73;

Jan1is;     Havickis;       13.12.1997; 161RDB267;

Arturs;     Zdanovs;        25.11.95;   161RDB204;  8.51;

Jelena;     Lomonosova;     10.08.1997; 141REC012;  9.34;

Kirils;     Volodins;       03.06.1998; 161RDB338;  7.88;

Maksims;    Sokolovs;       14.03.1997; 161VDB003;  6.78;

Matiss;     Janovskis;      27.02.1995; 161RDB249;  8.01;

Anna;       Matveeva;       30.07.1994; 111RMB006;  7.51;

Polina;Aleksandrova;    17.05.1998; 161RDB251;  Praktikants;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    printf("Atverts fails ar sekojosam strukturam :\n\n");

    FILE *fp;
    FILE *err;

    char buf[10000];

    fp = fopen("3_161VDB001.txt", "r");
    err = fopen("err.txt", "a");

    while (!feof(fp))   {
        fgets(buf, 100000, fp);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    printf("\n\nSakartotas strukturas:\n\n");


    struct Students {
        char name[30];
        char surname[30];
        char birth[11];
        char number[20];
        char mark[10];
        double nummark;
    };

    struct Students info[100];

    int i,k, nn, snmn, bdn, numb, mrk, count = 0, t;
    int j, low, max;

    for (i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        if (buf[i] == '\n'){
            printf("%c\t%c\t%c\t%c\t%.2lf\n", info[k].name[nn], info[k].surname[snmn], info[k].birth[bdn], info[k].number[numb], info[k].nummark);
            max = i;

            if (count != 5 || info[k].nummark == 0 || isdigit(info[k].birth[0]) == 0 || isdigit(info[k].birth[1]) == 0 || //proverka na korrektnostj dati
            isdigit(info[k].birth[3]) == 0 || isdigit(info[k].birth[4]) == 0 || isdigit(info[k].birth[6]) == 0 ||
            isdigit(info[k].birth[7]) == 0 || isdigit(info[k].birth[8]) == 0 || isdigit(info[k].birth[0]) == 9 || 
            info[k].birth[2] != '.' || info[k].birth[5] != '.') {   //proverka na nevernoe kolichestvo elementov strukturi
                    for (j=0; j<(max - low); j++)   {
                        fprintf(err, "%c", buf[j]);
                    }
            }
            nn = 0, snmn = 0, bdn = 0, numb = 0, count = 0; //podgotovka k sled strukture
            low = i+1; k++;
        }
        if (buf[i] == ';') {            //konec elementa strukturi
            if (count == 0) {
                info[k].name[nn] = '\0';
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                info[k].surname[snmn] = '\0';
            }
            if (count == 2) {
                info[k].birth[bdn] = '\0';
            }
            if (count == 3) {
                info[k].number[numb] = '\0';
            }
            if (count == 4) {
                info[k].mark[4] = '\0';
            }
            count++;                    //sled element strukturi
        }

        if (buf[i] == ' ' || buf[i] == '\t') {      //Propusk probelov i TABov
            continue;
        }

        if (count == 0) {           //Zanosim  imja  v  strukturu
            info[k].name[nn] = buf[i];
            nn++; 
        }

        if (count == 1) {           //Zanosim  familiju  v  strukturu
            info[k].surname[snmn] = buf[i];
            snmn++; 
        }

        if (count == 2) {           //Zanosim  datu rozhdenija  v  strukturu
            info[k].birth[bdn] = buf[i];
            bdn++;
        }

        if (count == 3) {           //Zanosim  nomer studenta  v  strukturu
            info[k].number[numb] = buf[i];
            numb++;
        }

        if (count == 4) {           //Zanosim  ocenku  v  strukturu
            info[k].mark[mrk] = buf[i];
            mrk++;
        }
    }

        for (i=0; i<=k; i++) { //ocenki perevodim v double
        info[k].nummark = strtod (info[k].mark, NULL);
        }

    for (i=0; i<=k; i++) {  
        printf("%c\t%c\t%c\t%c\t%.2lf\n", info[k].name[nn], info[k].surname[snmn], info[k].birth[bdn], info[k].number[numb], info[k].nummark);
    }

    printf("Strukturas ar kludam ir redzamas faila 'err.txt'");
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен парсер CSV формата: https://www.google.com/search?q=c+csv+library

Answer (score 0):

Явная проблема сдесь:

```
while (!feof(fp))   {
    fgets(buf, 100000, fp);
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

вы перезаписываете буфер каждый раз, когда вводится новая строка. В результате у вас сохраняется в массиве только последняя строка файла.

К тому же в дальнейшем вообще не понятно как данные из массива `buf` записываются в вашу структуру... Это не весь код?

Comment: Код весь, просто, видимо, неверно использовал функцию. Подразумевалось, что вами указанной строкой содержимое txt и заносилась в буфер, а из него уже в структуры построчно (большой цикл for, где все это и видно). Спасибо за наводку, попробую исправить это.